# What does "Protocol Requires Function with Type" mean?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm using a delegate to pass a value I have stored within a function. Whenever I try to implement the delegate into my another class, I get the error "AnswerViewController" does not conform to protocol "TagToIndex Delegate". Expanded, the error yields:

> Protocol requires function 'finishPassing(dictionary:)' with type '(Dictionary)->()' do you want to add a stub?

Here is the protocol:

```
protocol TagToIndexDelegate {
func finishPassing (dictionary:Dictionary<Int,Int>)
}
```

Here is the function I am trying to send the variable from:

```
extension MyCell: YSSegmentedControlDelegate {

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {
    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index

    delegate?.finishPassing(dictionary: tagToIndex)
}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int) {

}}
```

Where `delegate` is of type `TagToIndexDelegate`, and the variable `tagToIndex` which exists within `willPressItemAt` is the data I am passing.

And finally, the class I am trying to implement `TagToIndexDelegate`

```
class AnswerViewController: UIViewController, TagToIndexDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
}
```

I feel like I've made some kind of fundamental error, but I'm not familiar enough with Swift to know what the error is.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1):

You have defined protocol `TagToIndexDelegate` which requires the method `finishPassing (dictionary:Dictionary<Int,Int>)`implemented. Then, you say that your `AnswerViewController` class conforms to `TagToIndexDelegate`, but you never actually implement the required method. That class needs to implement the required method in order to satisfy conformance.

You can add a stub as the error suggests which would be:

```
func finishPassing (dictionary:Dictionary<Int,Int>)
{
  // logic here
}
```

You can also change the protocol function declaration to optional by adding `optional` in front of it like this:

`optional func finishPassing (dictionary:Dictionary<Int,Int>)`

As for what is the right thing to do, you'll have to decide that based on what's actually supposed to be happening in your app.